# Getting Fabric Python Library to Work

Tags: python, pip, fabric, homebrew

I installed Fabric via Pip, which was installed via Homebrew (OS X 10.6.6). The Fabric library is where pip says it should be, however I cannot get a basic fabfile going.

I've tried the simple hello world example found here: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/tutorial.html

Bash gives me the following error when I try *fab hello*: 
***-bash: fab: command not found***

Paths:

- Python 2.7.1: /usr/local/bin/python
- pip libraries: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages

I'm probably overlooking something silly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: im guessing the fab command is not in your path..where did it get installed?  whereis fab

Answer (score 6):

When you install Fabric with Homebrew and Pip, `fab` gets put at `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/bin/fab`. Make sure `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/bin` is on your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, I had the wrong path. I switched it from `export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH` to `export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/bin:$PATH` and I'm in business. Gracias!